# Boolean set of conditions

Tags: iis, mobile, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am currently rewriting URLs for my mobile website version with rules like that:

```
<rule name="MOBILE example rule" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
   <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">                                                                         
      <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="mobile|phone" />
      <add input="{HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent}" pattern="mobile|phone" />
      <add input="{HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}" pattern="mobile|phone" />                        
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/mobile/index.php?lang={R:1}&amp;cat={R:2}&amp;brn={R:3}&amp;mdl={R:4}" />
</rule>
```

Then, in case user wants to visit the "classic" desktop version of the website, I set a "forceNotMobile" cookie to "true".

The question is... what kind of condition may I add to have this behavior:

- if the cookie is set, then the rules works and rewrite the URL;
- else if the cookie is NOT set, or equals false, I stop rules processing whitout rewriting anything;

I suppose I'm looking for something like that:

```
<add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="forceNotMobile=true" negate="true" />
```

but then the "MatchAny" logical grouping should be "MatchAll", and that's not compliant with my set of "ua-is-mobile" rules.

Can I add two `<conditions />` blocks?

PS. is my way for checking wheter UA is mobile right? how can I improve it? I only want smartphones to be "rewrited" to my mobile version.